# How different are the industry jobs specific to Ph.D vs jobs where both Ph.D/MS are hired?

Tags: hiring, qualification

My question is specific to the context of Computer Science/Computer Engineering in the US. I assume industries hire graduate degree holders for positions where the degree requirement is:

- (1) MS or Ph.D, or
- (2) only Ph.D

Even with the second category (2) "Only Ph.D" I assume (again) there could be 2 types of jobs :

- (2.1) Research based roles
- (2.2) Engineering/development role with no research component.

My question is: What makes (2.2) special that it needs a Ph.D and so cannot be done with an MS?

Again, I could be over-simplifying things here and over-assuming (or even plain wrongly assuming), but since I haven't had such industry exposure, I am just very curious to understand how things work in the industry for Ph.D graduates.

Comment: Your assumption is flawed. PhD is a research degree, whether academic or commercial.

Comment: The skills acquired by a PhD is rarely needed in the industry unless they need razor sharp knowledge about a very specific field that the graduate has worked with.

Comment: For technical disciplines "Ph.D only" if quite rare. In most cases it's either both or "M.Sc. + x years" vs "Ph.D. + y years" . Degree only matters for the the first few years of industry,. After you are 5 years in, no one cares anymore. Experience wins over academia hands down.

Comment: @keshlam i was aware im probably assuming wrong, hence the point of the question - to find out what i got it wrong and what is right out there.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is: What makes "**Engineering/development role with no research component**" special that it needs a Ph.D and so cannot be done with an MS?

**Answer: Nothing makes that role so special that only a PhD can do it**.

A software engineer with a BS or MS degree can do software development **perfectly** well for a great majority of tech companies (probably more than 99.99% if not 100% of the companies).

It certainly does not require a PhD to do this kind of job.

*Note: Of course, a PhD may be a "plus", but is not a "must-have" requirement for this kind of position.*

Comment: In fact, there's a growing trend toward believing that for entry-level programming tasks, many high-school grads have sufficient skills. I'm not convinced that's wise if you will ever want more than "code monkeys", but fact is that the days of programming per se being an elite skill are mostly behind us. Of course this means a lot more inefficient and/or buggy code gets written, but people want it to be cheap so...

Comment: @keshlam I would be careful with that "of course". It might well be that efficiency or the number of bugs correlates much stronger with years of coding experience than with a university degree, so candidates with a high school and a couple of years spent coding can be better on average than fresh university graduates

Comment: Except that the other choice is the same population _plus_ the additional focused exposure and practice.